# Как обновить версию php в Open Server до php 7.1.3?

Tags: php7, openserver, laravel-5.7

При установке проекта получаю ошибки вида:

> composer update
>
> - laravel/framework v5.7.3 requires php ^7.1.3 ->
>     your PHP version (7.0.14) does not satisfy that requirement.

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.0.0",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "laravel/framework": "5.7.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
        "laravelcollective/html": "*",
        "lavary/laravel-menu": "^1.7",
        "intervention/image":"*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^3.2",
        "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "^2.5",
        "beyondcode/laravel-dump-server": "^1.0",
        "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^2.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "Corp\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": [
            ]
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
            "php artisan ide-helper:generate",
            "php artisan ide-helper:meta"
        ]

    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

Comment: В настройках вкладка `Модули` - ставите нужные вам модули, в т. ч. и php

Comment: @ InDevX у меня в модулях php до версии 7.1*64, а нужно 7.1.3 Придётся видимо сносить и ставить новую версию OS